# Nearest point property and uniformly continuous image

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, uniform-continuity

Show that a uniformly continuous image of a metric space that has the nearest point property need not have that property.

I have some trouble understanding the problem.
With the term ''uniformly continuous image'' does it mean that $f(X)=Y$ where $f$ is uniformly continuous ?

Comment: About the second question: Yes.

Comment: So i need to show that $f$ does not need the property of nearest point to be uniformly continuous ?

Comment: As I understand this you need to find a metric space $X$ which satisfies the nearest point property and a uniformly continuous function $f$ such that $f(X)$ does not satisfy the nearest point property.

Comment: What is the nearest point property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not know this nearest point property, but I found it in [Google books](https://books.google.nl/books?id=aP37I4QWFRcC&pg=PA121&lpg=PA121&dq=%22nearest+point+property%22+metric+space&source=bl&ots=wFNroM5HD2&sig=nyo28goQAPpDZwxdd-7kHg6FEX0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwip3oKdm6ffAhWi4YUKHaU9CqcQ6AEwA3oECAUQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22nearest%20point%20property%22%20metric%20space&f=false) and there the author gives the following equivalent formulations:

- Every infinite bounded subset of $X$ has an accumulation point in $X$.
- Every bounded sequence has a subsequence that converges in $X$.
- $X$ is complete and every bounded subset is totally bounded.

Now consider $X = \mathbb{N}$ in the usual metric, which has the nearest point property. And note that $f(n) = \frac{1}{n}$ is uniformly continuous onto a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ that does not have that property.

Comment: How about $(X,d_0)$ where $|X|=\infty$? If we take $f:X\rightarrow X$ then $f$ is uniformly continuous but it does not have the nearest point property when $X$ is infinite

Comment: @argiriskar what is $d_0$? If it is the discrete metric then it does not obey the NPP

Comment: @argiriskar nearest point property

Comment: yes i undestood that after i posted the question. But that's the point of the problem. We don't want the function to obey the NPP

Comment: @argiriskar the domain has to obey NPP but the image not. Like in my example.

Comment: How can i contact you in private so that we don't fill up the comments? I have some questions that i want to ask you.

Comment: @argiriskar ask a new question ? That’s what this site is for.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87198/discussion-between-argiriskar-and-henno-brandsma).